# Where IOchardServices gets its concrete class set?

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

I am looking at the Orchard source and am looking for where the IOchardServices gets its concrete injected. I realize that all one has to do is specify the IOchardServices as a param in a controller constructor and it'll get injected, but I want to know where Autofac actually does it. I was looking at '/Orchard/Environment/OrchardStarter.cs' and there are many builder..... calls and so it looks like injection is occurring there; did a search in that file for IOchardServices and didn't find it.

The reason I'm interested in this is, I need to do property injection on aspx pages' codebehind since our team will only be able to slowly migrate over to Orchard CMS and we'll need to keep our existing pages as is, well without too much modification. I also assume that when we have our own custom interfaces we'll want to inject and will need to know the best place to do this.

Comment: This was cross-posted from this: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/265781

Answer (score 0):

The actual injection is done within Autofac itself, not in the Orchard code. The autofac-configuration is done by several autofac-modules within Orchard-modules.

When you want to migrate to Orchard, you can just start by first using Autofac without Orchard. Define logical interfaces and put the Autofac-configuration in application_start in your global.asax. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Example/Remember.Web/Global.asax.cs) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration) for examples.